# Solr Query Exact Match and partial match search Querying

Tags: apache, search, solr, solr4

I have to search some documents with exact match and partial matches.
For an example : i have documents with title called "ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE". I want to search ABC-01 With high score (Exact match the search term in the title) Also I want to search documents contains ABC-01. Also It should sorted according to the score and date in desc order . 
Also there is an another field called driver . search also should search the driver field with lower score than title exact match or parital match.

(Please Note Exact match search only "ABC-01" Not "ABC-010")
Any Clues on this ?

- id:ABC-01
- Title :ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE
- joinedDate:2016-01-10

---

- id:ABC-010
- Title :ABC-001010 IS AVAILABLE
- joinedDate:2016-01-12
- Driver:ABCMAN

  ---
- id:XYZ-05
- Title :XYZ-05 CAB IS IS AVAILABLE,ABC-01-XE IS AVAILABLE
- joinedDate:2015-01-12 
  Driver:ABCD MAN ABC-01

---

- id:ABC-07
- Title :ABC-07 IS AVAILABLE ABC-01-XE
- joinedDate:2015-01-12
- Driver:CD MAN ABC-05

For this example 
if i search ABC-01

### - I wanted the follwoing Resuls

- id:ABC-01
- Title :ABC-01 IS AVAILABLE
- joinedDate:2016-08-12
- Driver:ABCMAN

---

- id:XYZ-05
- Title :XYZ-05 CAB IS IS AVAILABLE,ABC-07 IS AVAILABLE
- joinedDate:2015-01-12
- Driver:ABCD MAN ABC-01

---

- id:ABC-07
- Title :ABC-07 IS AVAILABLE ABC-01-XE
- joinedDate:2015-01-11
- Driver:CD MAN ABC-05

Please If The search term is available as exact match  in title it should highly scored.
OR If not it should search title field contains ABC-01 or abc-01-xe or whatever contains abc-01.
Also It should search driver field to find any related driver for the given term.

Results should be sorted according to score as well as date.
Also Exact match recent date should be displayed first with the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions in one here.

You can search multiple fields with eDisMax and give different weights to different fields to sort.

You can sort by function queries that mix score and date and experiment until you get the right mix.

Matching ABC-01-xe against ABC-01 is a bit harder, as it is not clear what you mean. It is going to be some sort of index-time analyzer chain element, but which one depends on the specific of your mapping. Is ABC-01-ANYTHING maps to ABC-01, or it has to be ABC-01-xe specifically. What about ABC-01234? You need to get the business rule of this mapping first and then work on insuring that - at the end of the index-time analyzer chain - you got what you wanted. You may also want to have two fields with the same information processed differently and one with less processing (e.g. ABC-01 exact) having higher weight.

Comment: ABC-01-WHATEVER Should match ABC-01.,,,

Comment: What about ABC-01234? That's significant because the question is boundaries. Are you breaking on '0' or are you matching on prefix?

Comment: I take "ABC-01" as seach term . I should search whatever Contains ABC-01 in above mentioned fields. :) example : if Input is abc-01 it should return the results
 ABC-01,
 blah blah blah ABC-01 ,
ABC-01 Blah Blah,Foo Bar ABC-01XXX,ABC-01-0111 FOO BAR . ")

Comment: Then you might be looking for [Edge N-grams|https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions?focusedCommentId=38571041#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter], but the issue is whether your prefix is always 5-characters long. If it is not. E.g. if Taxi id could be XYZ-5678 and you need to normalize to that, you are back to trying to figure out the business rule of identifying what the prefix is.

Answer (score 1):

Edited response:
As Alexandre pointed out, you assign weight with edismax. For the sake if fun, if you add the sample data at the bottom to a test core and run the following search it gives you the right order of cabs.

http://.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8983/solr/abc123/select?defType=edismax&indent=on&q=id:ABC-01*%20ORTitle:*ABC-01*&qf=id^1.5%20Title^0.7&wt=json

In the regular query, you have a plain vanilla wild-card search with an OR:

```
id:ABC-01* 
OR
Title:*ABC-01*
```

[image]
Then you enable edismax and assign weights, I pumped up id by 1.5 and reduced Title to 0.7 as in:

```
id^1.5 Title^0.7
```

[image]

The response is as follows:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":23,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:ABC-01* \nOR\nTitle:*ABC-01*",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "indent":"on",
      "qf":"id^1.5 Title^0.7",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1477029831405"}},
  "response":{"numFound":13,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"ABC-01",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-10T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778151323107328},
      {
        "id":"ABC-010",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-14T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778151552745472},
      {
        "id":"ABC-01234",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-14T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778803999801344},
      {
        "id":"ABC-02",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-11T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778151538065408},
      {
        "id":"ABC-03",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-12T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778151548551168},
      {
        "id":"ABC-04",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-13T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778151549599744},
      {
        "id":"XYZ-04",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-13T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778151556939776},
      {
        "id":"ABC-07",
        "Title":["ABC-07 IS AVAILABLE ABC-01-XE"],
        "joinedDate":["2015-01-12T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778495705874432},
      {
        "id":"BBC-02",
        "Title":["ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. "],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-11T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778803994558464},
      {
        "id":"ABC-010101",
        "Title":["ABC-02 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABC01 CAB IS AVAILABLE"],
        "joinedDate":["2016-01-12T00:00:00Z"],
        "_version_":1548778803995607040}]
  }}
```

SAMPLE DATA to add:

```
 <add><doc>
<field name="id">ABC-01</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-10</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-02</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-11</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-03</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-12</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-04</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-13</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-010</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-14</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-07</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-07 IS AVAILABLE ABC-01-XE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2015-01-12</field>
</doc>

<doc>
<field name="id">XYZ-04</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-13</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">DBC-01</field>
<field name="Title">DBC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-10</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">BBC-02</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. </field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-11</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-010101</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-02 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABC01 CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-12</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-01QWERTY</field>
<field name="Title">CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. </field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-13</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-01234</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW. ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-14</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">ABC-007</field>
<field name="Title">ABC-007 IS AVAILABLE ABC-01-XE</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2015-01-12</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">XYZ-014</field>
<field name="Title"> ABCDE CAB IS AVAILABLE. ABC-01 CAB IS BUSY RIGHT NOW.</field>
<field name="joinedDate">2016-01-13</field>
</doc></add>
```

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:
You are probably looking to have something along the lines of:

```
id:ABC-01* OR id:*ABC
```

The query in the URL would look like this:

```
http:<server>:8983/solr/<core>/select?indent=on&q=id:ABC-01*%20OR%20id:*ABC&wt=json
```

Comment: Raza, is this what you are looking for? Can you give a few more examples of the input and the expected output so we can hone it down a lil more? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment 
Lefty G Balogh . please look my edited question.

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining ,,